# Sudo directive to read a log file

Tags: files, sudo

This works:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

but this does not:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/log/maillog
```

It says: "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified."

The path is correct. Am I missing something here? Thoughts?

Adding a space after `NOPASSWD:` did not make it work. I am calling a `.sh` file from PHP that just has this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep bounced /var/log/maillog
```

I added a path to both the script and the log file but it just doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need a space after `NOPASSWD:`. Does that make it work? If not, how are you invoking sudo (not from the command line apparently, so: from a crontab?)?

Comment: That did not make it work. I am calling a .sh file from PHP that just has this in it: "#!/bin/sh grep bounced /var/log/maillog". I added a path to both the script and the log file but it just doesn't work.

Comment: your 2nd sudo directive is simply the path to the log file; it should be the name of the script that you are invoking with sudo. Assuming you have a web server running as apache with a PHP page; is PHP calling `sudo somescript.sh`? Otherwise, you could add "grep bounced /var/log/maillog" as the sudo rule and update your script to `sudo` _that_

Comment: I tried "apache          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: grep bounced /var/log/maillog" but it's giving me a syntax error. What's the proper way to update the rule to just allow that command?

Comment: use the full path and filename of the script that contains the grep command in your sudo rule.

Comment: I tried that already. And I tried creating a Cmnd_Alias with both paths in there. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sudoers line

> ```
> apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/log/maillog
> ```

allows the `apache` user to *execute* the file `/var/log/maillog`. But your script executes `grep`, so that line doesn't apply.

Sudo works by command. There's no way to use it to allow accessing a specific file with any command. You could allow the command `grep bounced /var/log/maillog`, if that's all you want. But if what you want is simply to allow the `apache` user to read from `/var/log/maillog` with any program, then what you should do is add `apache` to the access control list for that file.

```
setfacl -m user:apache:r /var/log/maillog
```

This command needs to be executed every time the file is re-created due to log rotation. [This is done automatically with recent enough versions of logrotate](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=666677). If your version is too old, [add that command to your logrotate configuration as a `postrotate` entry](https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?3589-logrotate-doesn-t-honor-file-ACL).

Comment: Looks like I have Logrotate version 3.7.8, so, no go. Can you give me an example of how I can just allow the command grep bounced /var/log/maillog? I can't figure out the syntax (see comments above).

Comment: @tgurske Use a postrotate directive, that should work with any version of logrotate. If you want to use sudo, `apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: grep bounced /var/log/maillog` is right.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work. Gives a syntax error and doesn't work if I save it anyway. I give up. Postrotate directive is going to be my best bet I think. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @tgurske Actually you need the full path to `grep`, e.g. `/usr/bin/grep`. But the postrotate directive is the right way to solve this, don't bother with sudo, it isn't the right tool for this job.